# Connecting SQL Data to R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I am having some difficulty trying to understand what I am doing wrong. I am extremely new to R.  I am attempting to connect my SQL Server to R via ODBC.  Here is the code I am using.

```
> library(odbc)
> library(DBI)
> library(ggplot2)
> unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]])
[1] "SQL Server"                                            
[2] "SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0"                     
[3] "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"              
[4] "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)"
[5] "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"           
[6] "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"                         
[7] "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"                         
> con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc(),
+                       Driver="SQL Server",
+                       Server="DESKTOP-OHXXXDT",
+                       Database="AdventureWorks2014",
+                       Trusted_Connection="True")
```

I get the following error

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HYT00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Comment: What is the authentication you use to connect to a database?

Comment: Try `Trusted_Connection="Yes"` instead, but this is using Windows Authentication and requires that the current Windows user's account is registered in the target SQL Server instance. You may wish to use SQL Login credentials instead with `Uid="YourSqlUsername", Pwd="YourSqlP4ssw0rd"`.